# Getting Chrono C++ library (Boost::sandbox) to work

Tags: c++, boost, linker, scons

i wanted to try out [Chrono](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.Chrono) from the Boost sandbox. It seems to support a lot of stuff and should be stable.

I have Boost in version 1.44 installed on my system (incl. boost_system lib which is needed) and took the sandbox version (the download-version is older and misses for example the ratio.hpp file).

But it isn't compiling. Trying to compile the simple example from the documentation, with linking boost_system (in scons with LIBS=['boost_system']), the following error is occurring every time:

```
obj/main.o: In function `main':
/home/***/src/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `boost::chrono::system_clock::now()'
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

That seems to be a linker error. What did i do wrong? I have boost_system in version 1.44 linked (trough scons) and already tried the same with the older version 1.40.

Any tips? How did you setup your use of chrono?

Thanks.

sascha

**Edit:** [This thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/08/169593.php), which is talking about compatibility issues, let me think that the sandbox version of Chrono should be able to work with boost 1.44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [Installing Chrono](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/chrono/libs/chrono/doc/html/boost_chrono/users_guide/getting_started.html#boost_chrono.users_guide.getting_started.install) documentation, you either need to build and link the Chrono library, or define `BOOST_CHRONO_INLINED`.

I had problems building Chrono from the trunk checkout, but it's probably related to the type_traits incompatibility mentioned in the Chrono docs.

I was able to build the example program with the following SConstruct (after fixing namespace errors):

```
env = Environment(
    CPPDEFINES = ['BOOST_CHRONO_INLINED'],
    CPPPATH = ['/.../boost_1_44_0', ],
    LIBPATH = ['/.../boost_1_44_0/stage/lib', ],
    LIBS = ['boost_system'],
)

env.Program('chrono-test', 'main.cpp')
```

Comment: Yeah, i was aware of the needed define statement (if the  non-linking version is the one to use) but i was wrong in just defining this variable in the source once. After using CPPDEFINES in my Scons script (like in your example) everything is working fine. Thanks for your answer and thanks for your scons example. I'm using the trunk version of Chrono and just copied all the headers over my boost installation. There was no need for some fixes or further problems (but i don't know if the trunk version is patching some other libraries. Maybe that could be a problem for someone else).